# How to find string with particular format in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am displaying a several list of items in my div. I can have a string data some thing in this format. For example: 12H-912

Here 12(first 2 digits) represents the year last two characters.(for ex: 2012 it will be 12)
And "H" represents the month.(for jan - "A", feb - "B".. Aug - "H"). And 9 after "-" represents the day in the month. And 12(last two characters represents the primary key which i generate. This can be of any characters not only two i mean it can be 2 or 1223 or 232323..).

Now in jquery i would like to find the string with this format and i want to make it as hyperlink with some function called in it. Can any one please help to find the solution.

Comment: What did you try? Where does the data come from? Is it from an ajax call or is it static html? How does the HTML structure look like?

Comment: Actually the list of items come from database and i display those items in div..It is an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following regex to find the exact match

```
"12H-912".match(/^\d{2}[A-Z]\-\w+$/)
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply.. If i have an item some thing like this.."Claim 12H-912 has modified" in label. How to find that  particular text from the label.. can you please help.

Comment: "Claim 12H-912 has modified".scan(/\d{2}[A-Z]\-\w+/) will give you the result as ["12H-912"]. If there are no matches means the result will be an empty array. You can find from that.

Comment: try to match it with .text() of that label

Comment: (/\d{2}[A-Z]\-\d+/).exec("Claim 12H-912 has modified")

Comment: Ok thank you.. i had used like this if((/\d{2}[A-Z]\-\d+/).exec(mylabeltext)){ alert(mylabeltext); } It is working fine but now i want to place hyperlink to that particulat test that is for 12H-192 how to place it..

Comment: Do you want to place the hyperlink in the scanned data?

Comment: Yes. I need to get 12H-912 from the matched text and need to place hyperlink.Thank you.

Comment: 'Claim 12H-912 has modified'.replace(/(\d{2}[A-Z]\-\d+)/,"<a href='#'>$1</a>");

Answer (score 0):

Work data:

```
<div>this is a div with 12H-912</div>
<table>
    <tr><td>7H-9123123</td></tr>
    <tr><td>08A-912234</td></tr>    
    <tr><td>08132A-912234</td></tr>    
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Javascript:

```
$('body').ready(function(){
    $('div').each(function(){
        var html = $(this).html();
        if (html.match(/[0-9]{2}[A-H]{1}-[0-9]+/g)) {
            $(this).html(html.replace(/([0-9]{2}[A-H]{1}-[0-9]+)/g, '"$1"')); 
        }
    });

    // easier and safer when in a td (alone)
    $('td').each(function(){
        var html = $(this).html();
        if (html.match(/^[0-9]{2}[A-H]{1}-[0-9]+$/g)) {
            $(this).html(html.replace(/([0-9]{2}[A-H]{1}-[0-9]+)/g, '"$1"'));         
        }
    });
});​​​​​
```

​
Output:

```
this is a div with "12H-912"
7H-9123123
"08A-912234"
08132A-912234
```

I'll let you work out the hypperlink.
You can fiddle with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/fCJJb/